# Dropdown menu doesn't work on chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm developing [this site](http://sell-your-power.com/web/www/), which is almost completed, but there is a problem. the menu under "Products" can't be viewed on Chrome on mobile. It seems to work fine on the default Android and IOS browsers. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I can confirm this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out via javascript. On mobile, one click open menu, second click redirect you. :)

```
    var state;
$(".dropdown > a").click(function (event) {
    var isMenu = $(this).parent().find('ul').text();

    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        if (isMenu == "") {
            href = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location = href;
        } else {
            if (!state) {
                state = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                state = false;
                href = $(this).attr('href');
                window.location = href;
            }
        }

    } else {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = href;
    }
});
```